# This problem has been giving me headache for past couple of days. Please, Solve it for me..

Tags: arithmetic

Ram completed a piece of work in 10
days. When the work was extended
by 75%, Ram reduced his speed to (1/
A) times for the extended work. For the
same extended work only, Ravi took
(3.2B) days. If they worked together
to finish the initial work (excluding
extended work), they would take 480/47
days and 160/21 days if Ram worked at his
slower and faster speeds respectively,
during his entire work. 
Then A + B = ? (Take A & B upto two
decimal places)

[Question in figure ]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMnIh.png)

Answer (score 2):

At his normal pace, the ram does $1$ Job in $10$ Days. That is, it works at $0.1$ Jobs/Day. At its slower pace, it does $0.1 / A$ Jobs/Day.

On the other hand, Ravi completes $0.75$ Jobs in the space of $3.2B$ Days, so he works $0.75 / (3.2B) = 0.234375 / B$ Jobs/Day.

If Ravi and the Ram cooperate, the Ram working at his faster pace (assuming the jobs can be parallelised perfectly), then they complete jobs at $0.1 + 0.234375 / B$ Jobs/Day. So, to complete one Job, it will take
$$\frac{1}{0.1 + 0.234375 / B} \text{ Days}.$$
Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{160}{21} = \frac{1}{0.1 + 0.234375 / B} &\iff \frac{21}{160} = 0.1 + \frac{0.234375}{B} \\
&\iff \frac{0.234375}{B} = \frac{21}{160} - \frac{1}{10} = \frac{5}{160} = \frac{1}{32} \\
&\iff B = 32 \cdot 0.234375 = 32 \cdot \frac{0.75}{3.2} = 7.5.
\end{align*}
Now, use the corresponding data where the Ram works at a slower pace to figure out $A$.